# Simulation tools for centralized, decentralized, or distributed wireless sensor network

Tags: sensors, protocols, wireless

I want to simulate the collision avoidance between different objects that use (IoT based) centralized, decentralized, or distributed wireless sensor network. What are free software available to achieve my goal? I would like to know which one is easiest to learn. I tried [cupcarbon](http://www.cupcarbon.com/) but couldn't find tutorials of my interest. Thanks.

Comment: Hi maxpayne, what exactly do you want to simulate? Which OSI-layer are you talking about. Collisions on signal, package or application level?

Comment: @Helmar Collision avoidance system is the main goal through knowing position of sensors in the field or through rssi. But i am currently interesting in simulating the various nodes in different areas. Communication of nodes to each other, sending receiving singnals, setup sink, router, server, etc in the system.

Comment: Still, collision avoidance on which layer are you interested in? RSSI screams level 1, collision avoidance is usually done level 2 upwards.

Comment: Yes, right. RSSI at level 1 and collision at level 2.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [emane](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/emane) project (usually paired with the [core](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/core) project).

This project lets you build emulations of the raw radio layer and then add the higher level network layers on top.